# If $\alpha$ is a tautology and $\beta$ a contingency then $(\alpha $ and $\beta) $ is equivalent to $\beta$.

Tags: logic

If $\alpha$ is a tautology and $\beta$ a contingency then $(\alpha $ and $\beta) $ is equivalent to $\beta$.

This is a pretty basic statement in logic, but I don't know how to prove it, could you guys give me a hand?

Comment: Could you try to write out your $\implies$ and $\equiv$ in words and complete sentences instead? It is a bit difficult to parse your claim.

Comment: Note that if $\alpha$ is a tautology, then $\alpha\lor\beta$ is also a tautology, and in particular it won't in general be logically equivalent to $\beta$.

Comment: Oops, I meant "and". Fixed it. @HenningMakholm I also cleared up the question.

Comment: Use a truth table.

Comment: @MikePierce Truth tables won't work for the general case - $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not even formulas. I would go for a somewhat generalized version of the argument, which is like the solution I point out below.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that, order-theoretically speaking, the classical $\text{and}$ operator, $\phi \land \psi$, corresponds to the a meet of two elements of a Boolean algebra $\langle \{0,1\},\leq \rangle$, so that we usually define

$$v(\phi \land \psi) = \text{min}\{v(\phi),v(\psi)\}$$

Knowing this, it's easy to see that for any tautology $\alpha$ and contingency $\beta$, $v(\beta) = \text{min}\{v(\alpha),v(\beta)\}$, for any valuation map $v$ that you may choose.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more the first part? In my class, $v(p \wedge q)$ was defined as $\min(v(p),v(q))$ and $v:\text{FORM} \to \textbf 2$ is called a valuation.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Let $\alpha$ be an arbitrary tautology. Then $v(\alpha)=1$ for every valuation $v$. Thus - and this is the kernel of the argument -, $\text{min}\{1,v(\beta)\}=v(\beta)$ for any $\beta$: for if $v(\beta)=1$, $\text{min}\{1,1\}=1$; otherwise, $v(\beta)=0$ and $\text{min}\{1,0\}=0$. Particularly, if $\beta$ is any contingency, so will be $\alpha \land \beta$.